# Firebase Cloud Messages never reach the device

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm implementing FCM on Ionic 2 (AngularFire2 &  Ionic Native FCM: cordova-plugin-fcm@2.1.2) currently testing iOS on an iOS 11 device.

FCM messages never arrive on the device.  I get no errors from either the console sending messages or when sending messages via cURL.

I've gone through the troubleshooting steps from the [Google dev advocate](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html).

I've verified that a notification sent directly via Apple's APNS server gets delivered to the device when the app is in background, and the app when the app is in foreground.  (I pulled the actual device token to test this.)  i.e. APNS certificates are fine.

FCM initializes with no errors (watching the logs in Xcode) and FCM does retrieve a (seemingly) valid FCM token.

I've just ensured that all my npm modules are at the latest versions for firebase, angularFire2 and fcm.

I've verified that 'GoogleService-Info.plist' is in my resources folder

Bottom line: My APNS certificate is valid and seems to be correctly setup in the Firebase console.  APNS direct messages work fine.  FCM messages don't return an error, they just never get to the device.  Seems to be getting lost in the FCM end.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to further debug this?

thx.

Comment: Do you have an Android to test there too?

Comment: I do not have an Android device, just the emulator.

Comment: pacakge ID was my issue once.

Comment: I've got the 'Bundle ID', 'App Store ID' and 'App ID Prefix' all set correctly.  I've reset them multiple times to be sure.  thanks.